# Weird resolution

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hdmi, video, noobs

So, im new to the raspberry pi. When i first started it and installed the raspian os with noobs, it had fine resolution. But then i rebooted, and for some reason the noobs menu was in alright resolution but when raspbian os started up it hat a really small resolution that was way behind the maximum of my TV! I am plugged in trough a HDMI cable on my TV that has a resolution a bit better than 720p resolution. Anyone knows whats happening?
[image: noobs menu]
[image: raspbian os]

Photos of tvservice -s and tvservice -m;tvservice -m DMT
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: What do you get from the following commands  ```TV service -s``` & ```tvservice -m CEA;tvservice -m DMT``` as they will tell you what mode your Raspberry & TV have negotiated.

Comment: `TV service -s` should  be `tvservice -s`

Comment: Bloody phone with DYAC doesn't like tvservice. It likes to make it into TV service, because it knows better than me.

Answer (score 1):

Under the applications menu, select Preferences,Raspberry Pi Configuration. Then select 'Set Resolution' and choose your resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i have disabled overscan in the raspberry pi configuration menu and now it works!